# Image segmentation with U-net

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to understand if Semantic segmentation with U-NET. Are we training kernels to extract features or are we training a fully connected layer at the end? Or both? If so, how are we training them? how are we using the loss function to train them? Because based on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLr3Y.png) picture, i don't think there is a need for a fully connected layer at the end. If we just train our kernels, U-net will just do the image segmentation. I couldn't find any resource for "how to train unet model for image segmentation" so i wanted to ask here. Thanks in advance

Comment: In a U-Net you indeed do not use any fully connected layers. A U-Net consists of an encoder and decoder part which both fully consist of convolutional layers. When training a U-Net for semantic segmentation you can choose from multiple different loss functions such as cross-entropy loss or the DICE coefficient.

Comment: @Oxbowerce thank you for answer very much. Okay i understood. So for example we are using DICE coefficient, including 1x1 kernel every kernel will be updated based on that lose?

Comment: Yes, that is how neural networks work. Based on the loss the parameters of the network get updated to minimize that loss.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I was so confused because in image classification we are training both classifier(FCC) and architecture that we will use for feature extraction. Now I learned that in u-net architecture we are not training 2 different things.